# Rally Rest Api-Android app-Getting No class found even after importing required jars

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, rally

I am trying to build a rally Android app.I tried https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava As given I have added the jars.
1.commons-codec-1.6.jar
2.gson-2.2.4.jar
3.httpclient-4.2.5.jar
4.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
5.httpcore-4.2.4.jar

My mainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils;



    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
String applicationName = "Android-Rally";
RallyRestApi restApi;
Button buttonlogin;
EditText etemail,etpass;
QueryRequest qtestset;
QueryResponse response;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etemail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);
    etpass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
    buttonlogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(etemail.equals("") && etpass.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter your Rally Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    getRally();
                }
                catch (URISyntaxException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                qtestset = new QueryRequest("Defects");
                qtestset.setLimit(1);
                try
                {
                    response = restApi.query(qtestset);
                    if(!response.wasSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Un-Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }


        }
    });

}

public RallyRestApi getRally() throws URISyntaxException {
    String password = etemail.getText().toString();
    String email=etpass.getText().toString();
    restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host), email,password);
    restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);
    return restApi;
}
}
```

My error log

> 04-18 14:07:16.299 11364-11364/com.example.apetkar.rally_poc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   04-18 14:07:16.299 11364-11364/com.example.apetkar.rally_poc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.apetkar.rally_poc, PID: 11364
>                                                                                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method extractHost(Ljava/net/URI;)Lorg/apache/http/HttpHost; in class Lorg/apache/http/client/utils/URIUtils; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
>                                                                                      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.getHttpHost(DecompressingHttpClient.java:113)
>                                                                                      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:108)
>                                                                                      at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.executeRequest(HttpClient.java:157)
>                                                                                      at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.doRequest(HttpClient.java:145)
>                                                                                      at com.rallydev.rest.client.BasicAuthClient.doRequest(BasicAuthClient.java:56)
>                                                                                      at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.doGet(HttpClient.java:221)
>                                                                                      at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.query(RallyRestApi.java:172)
>                                                                                      at com.example.apetkar.rally_poc.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Can anyone help here..stuck at this for days now..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does android run some special mobile version of java?  It seems like the 4.2 http components are likely not compatible.  I haven't had a chance to look into it much, but I wonder if there is a newer set of those components that are compatible with the android environment?  You could try forking the RallyRestToolkitForJava repo and updating the dependencies locally to see if you can get it to run...

Comment: I got over it.Android does not support HTTP client jar that I added.There are different dependencies that are used for android.I changed the imports in the RestAPI classes to the one added in android.Thanks for you help.

Comment: Will do!  Which version of the HttpClient did you use that was supported?  It's probably about time to update the deps anyway...

Comment: HttpClient-4.4.1.1.jar contains all the files required which are in both client and core given in the documentation.I have configured it for android.If you want I can send it to you to have a look.It'll be easy for you

Comment: Also I did'nt get why the RallyRestApi's method email password is deprecated..I mean for android or any mobile development that one will be widely used instead of API key

Comment: That's a good point.  I guess we never anticipated much mobile usage when we made that decision.  Probably worth un-deprecating in a new version.  If you get a chance to share your code with me that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There's a class conflict with the included Apache HTTP jars and the ones used by native Android.  I got around this by forking the Rally project and replacing Apache HTTP with OKHttp to remove the conflict.  My changes are in my fork in github: https://github.com/rawslaw/RallyRestToolkitForJava

Comment: I got it working with apache http-client 4.1.1.1.jar..That jar targets the android version.I went through your code.Thanks anyways